# What is the "silk road" and what does it have to do with bitcoin?

Tags: marketplace, silk-road

I have read a lot about the silk road and I am still unsure what it is. I went to http://silkroadmarket.org but it just says that the site is down.

Comment: This site is about Bitcoin and other Crypto currencies. It cannot possibly become about any business that happens to accept bitcoins unless the *primary* focus of the question is the bitcoin technology or similar issues.

Comment: @Robert - Asking about "businesses" that are primarily Bitcoin, especially *enabled* by Bitcoin is on topic IMO. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Silkroad is an [anonymous online marketplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road_%28anonymous_marketplace%29) inside the [Tor network](https://www.torproject.org/) which became famous for selling illegal drugs.

They don't have anything to do with the Bitcoin project, except for the fact that they accept bitcoins as a payment method.

Comment: It also sells books. Got a few good books on there.

Answer (score 4):

Silkroad is a [Tor Hidden Service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) enabling supply and demand of/for (mostly illegal) goods & services to meet. Its onion address is http://silkroadvb5piz3r.onion/

Silkroad does not itself engage in selling goods or services, but merely offers a marketplace for doing this. Neither does it engage in handling payment or delivery.

A reputation system is in place to weed out the bad suppliers.

To be able to visit Silkroad you must make use of the [Tor Network](http://www.torproject.org/) and Onion Name Resolution. There are many HowTos on this, here is [one](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO).